# Multi drop down selection in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object, drop-down-menu

I have a error in my chrome console that I can not seem to solve.

I have a controller and front end code. The Idea is I have two drop downs, second is dependent on the first. they get the data from objects that have parent and child the second box shows the first boxes children.

Its worked for weeks, but I double check some functionality this morning and it seems to be broken and I am getting the error bellow.

can anyone see what is Wrong with the code ?

> **Error*TypeError: Cannot create property 'ProductType' on string 'Post Data Submitted Successfully!'
>       at Object.fn.assign (eval at compile (angular.js:15500), :4:431)
>       at Object.$$writeModelToScope (angular.js:29101)
>       at angular.js:29095
>       at g (angular.js:29014)
>       at e (angular.js:28997)
>       at Object.$$runValidators (angular.js:28941)
>       at Object.$$parseAndValidate (angular.js:29082)
>       at Object.$commitViewValue (angular.js:29048)
>       at Object.$$debounceViewValueCommit (angular.js:29186)
>       at Object.$setViewValue (angular.js:29166)*

**controller.js**

```
FirstModule.controller('dropDown', function ($scope) {
    console.log("First cnt dropDown LOADED");

    $scope.productsandformats = [
        {
            "name": "tom",
            "format": [
                {"Fname": "ddf", "id": "Roadside"},
                {"Fname": "ffr", "id": "roadsoop"},
                {"Fname": "Wfg(Digital)", "id": "fff"}
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "harry",
            "format": [
                {"Fname": "fef", "id": "4ee"},
                {"Fname": "fff (Digital)", "id": "derfere"}
            ]
        },

        {
            "name": "Supermarkets",
            "format": [
                {"Fname": "Asda ", "id": "asda"},
                {"Fname": "Sainsbury’s ", "id": "sains"}
            ]
        }];

    $scope.productTypeChange = function () {
        $scope.formats = $scope.productsandformats.find(ps => ps.name === $scope.formData.ProductType.name
    )
        //NG-Change
        $scope.myFunc = function () {
            var jsonItem = ($scope.formData.formatType.id);
            sessionStorage.setItem('format', jsonItem);
        }
    } });
```

**Front end angular**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div ng-controller="dropDown">

        <select ng-model="formData.ProductType.name" ng-change="productTypeChange()" ng-options="product.name as product.name for product in productsandformats">
            <option value="">- Please Choose -</option>
        </select>

        <select ng-model="formData.formatType" ng-options="format.Fname for format in formats.format" ng-if="formData.ProductType.name" ng-change="myFunc()">
            <option value="">- Please Choose -</option>
        </select>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="btn-group creative-format">
                <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="format" uib-btn-radio="'Roadside'">Roadside</label>
                <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="format" uib-btn-radio="'Digital'">Digital</label>
                <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="format" uib-btn-radio="'Billboard'">Billboard</label>
                <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="format" uib-btn-radio="'Premium'">Premium</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!--<div ng-controller="dropDown">-->
        <!--<button ng-click="myFunc()">send session</button>-->
        <!--</div>-->

        <!--<script>var jsonItem = JSON.stringify($scope.formData.ProductType.name);-->
        <!--sessionStorage.setItem('format', jsonItem);</script>-->

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There seems to be a " missing on line {"Fname": "fef", "id": "4ee}

Comment: lol, wow. thank you, unfortunately that is not the problem though just a error in the question form me

Comment: Why have you added the second ng-change function inside the first one?

Comment: ahh that's to pass data to a back end function

Comment: Move that function outside the first ng-change and was this ng-change even triggering?

Comment: Its triggers later on outside the function, ill try and remove it from the function.